# Creating Local Cache From ArcGIS Online Basemaps

Tags: arcgis-online, cache

I am contemplating creating a local caches from the standard ArcGIS Online Basemaps; streetmap, imagery and topo.  I need to do this because the environment the web application will be hosted is DOES NOT have live connection to the internet.  I have a couple of questions before I proceed:

1. Would creating a local tile cache from ArcGIS Online Basemaps violate any usage terms.  Without doing any research (yet), I am guessing the local tile cache would be subject to the same usage restrictions of the ArcGIS Online basemaps?
2. Assuming this is legal, is there anything in place that would prevent me from doing so?  Does anyone know if the ArcGIS Online servers start blocking an IP after *n* tile requests in *n* time period?

Any other thoughts,comments,suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you would be violating the "[Terms of Use](http://www.esri.com/legal/pdfs/g-577b-termsofuse.pdf)" (third party terms [here](http://www.esri.com/legal/licensing/third-party-data.html)).

It clearly says you cannot:

> Store the results derived from Licensee's use of Web Service(s) for
> the purpose of creating a value-added, Webenabled Application that
> Licensee intends to resell, license, or otherwise distribute to third
> parties without the prior  express written permission of Esri;

Regarding ESRI servers blocking IP, it says:

> ArcGIS Online Map Services, Imagery Services, and Geometry Services:
> You may put these Services to Commercial or  Non-Commercial Use, as
> determined by the license for the Application in which You embed these
> Services, subject to an  aggregate limit of 50,000,000 transactions
> during any twelve month period.

It would be best to write to them.  If they deem it as non-commercial they might just allow you.

Answer (score 5):

If you want the ArcGIS Online basemaps in-house ... you could also just buy the ArcGIS Data Appliance -  http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/data-appliance.

Answer (score 4):

There is a sample on how to store tiles into HTML5 web storage in ESRI JavaScript API. See [Sample: Tiles in Local Storage](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/jssamples/#sample/exp_webstorage)

Answer (score 2):

Check out this article reviewing [Cloud Web Mapping APIs](http://www.georelated.com/2012/10/cloud-web-mapping-service-api-review.html)

It has some of the answers you are looking for and handy links to the licensing docs. I think you will need to read the key sections yourself to make a call on this as offline usage depends very much on how you are planning to implement the solution.