# Create a local tile package from online world imagery

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, tiles

Is it possible to create a local tile package (.tpk file) containing data from an online source - for example something like world_imagery.mxd? ArcView 10.2 allows me to set up such a map document, but when I choose to Share As | Tile Package it says: 00005 Layer Type is not supported. I understand that it would need to download the images.

The point of this is to create an off-line base map. I've successfully created base maps from the EDN data that I downloaded from ESRI, but I don't have satellite imagery. An alternative would be a terrain map that shows shaded hills and mountains, but I don't see that on the edn data either.

Answer (score 3):

I believe this topic has already been address [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/11049/creating-local-cache-from-arcgis-online-basemaps). You have to understand that the satelitte imagery are not owned by Esri but by thrid party provider.

In short, you would be violating the "[Terms of Use](http://www.esri.com/legal/~/media/Files/Pdfs/legal/pdfs/e204_e300.pdf)" (third party terms [here](http://www.esri.com/legal/third-party-data)), which state (section 4.2.g):

> Store, cache, use, upload, distribute, or sublicense Content
>   or otherwise use Products in violation of Esri's or a third party's
>   rights, including intellectual property rights, privacy rights,
>   nondiscrimination laws, or any other applicable law or government
>   regulation;

Alternatively, you can purchase a [Data Appliance](http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/data-appliance) for off-line use.

Comment: The data appliance link isn't working for me.

Comment: @Paul I've double-checked and the link http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/data-appliance is still valid.  Alternatively, you can simply browse your way on the esri.com site by going to Products > Alphabetical List > Data Appliance for ArcGIS

Comment: the link is working for me now; who knows what the matter was yesterday. Thanks for looking into it. :)

Answer (score 0):

For your alternative question, you can use the cgiar [SRTM dataset resampled at 250 meters](http://srtm.csi.cgiar.org/) to create your own hillshaded layer (using the hillshade tool in arcGIS spatial analyst, or gdaldem for an open source solution). Just put the sun near the North for nice looking relief.

Answer (score -1):

Based on my experience, there are Esri base map services that are designed for use offline. However, only an end user can do that from within the Collector app or an app created using an ArcGIS Runtime SDK. The developer cannot have these prepared ahead of time for deployment with the app. The app must have the user log into ArcGIS Online using their own user login, or the app must connect to the developers account using an app login.

Search in ArcGIS Online content to see these exportable image tile maps: http://www.arcgis.com/home/search.html?q=owner%3Aesri%20export&t=content&focus=layers-weblayers-mapimage&start=1